Trying to locate an ssl certificate "sent by MX"
I am trying to diagnose an SSL certificate problem. I detected the issue using CheckTLS.com.

Certificate #1 of 3 (sent by MX): EXPIRED
Cert VALIDATION ERROR(S): certificate has expired
So email is encrypted but the recipient domain is not verified
Cert Hostname VERIFIED (townsendhardware.com = townsendhardware.com | DNS:townsendhardware.com)
Not Valid Before: Jul 18 11:54:10 2024 GMT
Not Valid After: Oct 16 11:54:09 2024 GMT
subject: /CN=townsendhardware.com
issuer: /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R11

My browser SSL certificate is valid and has no problems, so this certificate is coming from somewhere else. Using SSLShopper.com I checked both townsendhardware.com and, frankly on a whim, mail.townsendhardware.com. And there the little wombat is! There is no mail.townsendhardware.com subdomain, but I'm assuming that's what's meant by "sent by MX" in the CheckTLS.com out put.
Knowing there is no mail.townsendhardware.com subdomain, how can I track down the location of this certificate? I've been looking in the nginx.conf file and the associated vhost files, but as there is no subdomain, there isn't a vhost file and the linked certificates I have found are all valid.

Why do you include mail....? Your MX record (!) specify townsendhardware.com as MX. You do indeed run a mail server; have you checked what certificate it uses? Have you restarted it after renewing the certificate?

As a sidenote: You should probably upgrade. You are running ANCIENT software, and you're flaunting best practices by e.g. having MariaDB listening on public ports. If you have not been hacked, it's only a matter of time. Heck, your OpenSSH dates to 2016 (!).

@vidarlo I'm not including "mail." My mail server doesn't use it, nor do any of the clients connecting to it. But when I tested the SSL certs using it, suddenly the certificate causing all my problems popped up. On the other hand, I hadn't thought that postfix or dovecot might be looking at a certificate. I'll check that. Thanks.

You write in the question that you checked mail.townsendhardware.com which didn't exist... My impression is that you have no idea what software you're running, how it's configured, or if it's actually secure...

Running grep -Ei smtp.+tls /etc/postfix/main.cf should tell what to look for.

@vidarlo That's a nice thought, but I assumed the email clients might be automatically prepending the domain name regardless what the configuration settings said. Sonofagun, it revealed the problem. (I would have expected someone as harsh as yourself to have considerably more reputation than you have.)

@BobGoddard Thank you for that suggestion! I haven't found a fix yet, but it revealed yet two more PEM files to evaluate. The honkers are spread all over creation.

Have you attempted to restart the offending services?

@vidarlo Yes. Wherever the certificate causing my problem is, it's hanging around.

First, there is no such thing as a system-wide pem file. Each application must be told where to find the key & the cert. In main.cf, there WILL be lines which tell postfix what certs to use. No if's, no but's. You have to tell postfix explicitly where those files are. And since you are struggling, run the following to find where they are grep -Ei 'smtp[d]?_tls_(cert|key)_file' /etc/postfix/main.cf. Then run openssl x509 -text -noout -in <PATH_TO_CRT_FILE>to confirm.

@BobGoddard Thanks! That identified the evil bounder that's causing my problems. Man, that was a hard hunt.

The SSL certificate for the SMTP MX on townsendhardware.com has expired.
Repair your Let's Encrypt setup and renew.

how can I track down the location of this certificate?

It's on your Postfix mail server/MX. That has nothing to do with your nginx web server or any vhosts.

All of the dovecot vhost certificates have been upgraded. It appears that the culprit is a server-wide PEM file, but I've not proven that entirely (although the file creation date being the same as the not-before certificate date is suspicious). I'm working through how that's supposed to be updated, but haven't nailed it down yet.
